# Getting Message Digest from SHA1 message

Tags: openssl, cryptography, sha1

I am looking at this page on how to validate SHA1 implementation on a platform: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/secure-hashing.html#sha-1

So I open up the file and view the test values: https://pastebin.com/SL4WaAtM it is thousands of lines long but this is the start(BIT oriented implementations).

I focus on the first values:

```
Len = 2
Msg = 40
MD = ec6b39952e1a3ec3ab3507185cf756181c84bbe2
```

My understanding is that with a Message that openssl would get the MD, however I am not getting the same MD as that above?

```
 echo -n "40" | xxd -r -p | openssl dgst -sha1 
 (stdin)= 9a78211436f6d425ec38f5c4e02270801f3524f8
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?.Other values don't match either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [openssl sha1 not validating the nist input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43656920/openssl-sha1-not-validating-the-nist-input)

Comment: Almost cross-posted: [openssl sha1 message digest not matching with NIST vector input?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/46996/13022)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're interpreting the data incorrectly. `Len` is the number of *bits* in the message. By interacting with openssl on the command line, you are (to the best of my knowledge) restricted to working with whole bytes.

So for example `Len = 2` and `M = 40` means you should be hashing the first two bits of `0x40` (=`01`) and not the whole byte (`01000000`). On the command line, I don't think it's possible to feed openssl with bit streams that aren't a multiple of 8 bits in length, so you'll have to interface directly with the ssl library code if you want to do this.

However, you can test the bit patterns that are a multiple of 8 bits in length:

```
0 bits:
echo -ne "" | openssl sha1
(stdin)= da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709

8 bits:
echo -ne "\x5d" | openssl sha1
(stdin)= 4ff447b8ef42ca51fa6fb287bed8d40f49be58f1

16 bits:
echo -ne "\x53\xa1" | openssl sha1
(stdin)= c9066463926e470db1ba15cbd06e614dbf0bc9a7

etc...
```

Comment: The library interfaces of OpenSSL also work in units of bytes (of 8 bits). You'd need to change the code, or write your own. Which would be in scope for SO.